# My iPhone App doesn't work in iOS 4. Why?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I made an iPhone App that displays some video. I made it with Xcode 3.2.2 with iPhone SDK 3.1.3 and works fine. But a few days ago I downloaded the last version of the iPhone SDK for iOS 4. The project built OK, no erros, no warnings, but when I run the aplication the video didn't work, the image didn't load but sound works. I don't understand it.

Here is the code that I used.

```
NSBundle *Bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *moviePath = [Bundle pathForResource:@"Prueba" ofType:@"mp4"];
NSURL *movieURL = [[NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath] retain];
MPMoviePlayerController *theMovie = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
theMovie.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeFill;
[theMovie play];
```

Does someone have an idea?

Best regards.

Answer (score 2):

There is a new MPMoviePlayerViewController for 3.2 (ipad) and higher iOS4

More explanation in the DevForum https://devforums.apple.com/message/207339#207339

Answer (score 1):

You need to embed the movie player's view into your own view to see the video:

UIView* myView = ...
UIView* movieView = [moviePlayer view];
[movieView setFrame:[myView bounds]]; // fit the movie to the exact bounds of myView
[myView addSubview:movieView];

Comment: This worked for me, I just set myView to be the current controllers view, or in my case I added a modal view